# How do I group by one or more dimensions in a time series with Pandas?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, time-series

I have data like:

```
timestamp, country_code,  request_type,   latency
2013-10-10-13:40:01,  1,    get_account,    134
2013-10-10-13:40:63,  34,   get_account,    256
2013-10-10-13:41:09,  230,  modify_account, 589
2013-10-10-13:41:12,  230,  get_account,    43
2013-10-10-13:53:12,  1,    modify_account, 1003
```

Where timestamp is at second resolution and not regular.

How to express in pandas queries like:

- number of requests per country_code at a 10 minute resolution ?
- 99% percentile latency by request_type at a 1 minute resolution ?
- number of requests per country_code and request_type at a 10 minute resolution ?

and then graph all groups on the same graph, each as its own line over time.

**Update:**

based on the suggestion for 1. I have:

```
bycc = df.groupby('country_code').reason.resample('10T', how='count')
bycc.plot() # BAD: uses (country_code, timestamp) on the x axis
bycc[1].plot() # properly graphs the time-series for country_code=1
```

but can't seem to find the easy way to graph each country_code as a separate line with proper timestamps on the x axis and values on y. I think there are 2 problems (1) timestamps are not  the same for each country_code, they need to be aligned on the same start/end and (2) need to find the correct API/method to go from the multi-index TimeSeries object to a single plot with 1 line for each first value of the multi-index. Working my way ...

**Update 2**

The following seems to do it:

```
i = 0
max = 3
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 10.0) # get bigger graph
for cc in bycc.index.levels[0]:
    i = i + 1
    if (i <= max):
        cclabel = "cc=%d" % (cc)
        bycc[cc].plot(legend=True, label=cclabel)
```

printing only up to max values because it becomes noisy. 
Now on to figuring out how to better display plots with a lot of time series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE**: pandas cannot parse the datetime string "2013-10-10-13:40:63" because of the extra 4 seconds on the minute (which `dateutil` cannot parse; pandas uses dateutil to parse dates). I've converted it to "2013-10-10-13:40:59" for ease of exposition.

### 1. Number of Requests per `country_code` at a 10 minute resolution:

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]:
                     country_code    request_type  latency
timestamp
2013-10-10 13:40:01             1     get_account      134
2013-10-10 13:40:59            34     get_account      256
2013-10-10 13:41:09           230  modify_account      589
2013-10-10 13:41:12           230     get_account       43
2013-10-10 13:53:12             1  modify_account     1003

In [100]: df.groupby('country_code').request_type.resample('10T', how='count')
Out[100]:
country_code  timestamp
1             2013-10-10 13:40:00    1
              2013-10-10 13:50:00    1
34            2013-10-10 13:40:00    1
230           2013-10-10 13:40:00    2
dtype: int64
```

### 2. 99th percentile of `latency` by `request_type` at a 1 minute resolution

A very similar approach can be taken here as well:

```
In [107]: df.groupby('request_type').latency.resample('T', how=lambda x: x.quantile(0.99))
Out[107]:
request_type    timestamp
get_account     2013-10-10 13:40:00     254.78
                2013-10-10 13:41:00      43.00
modify_account  2013-10-10 13:41:00     589.00
                2013-10-10 13:42:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:43:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:44:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:45:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:46:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:47:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:48:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:49:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:50:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:51:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:52:00        NaN
                2013-10-10 13:53:00    1003.00
dtype: float64
```

### 3. number of requests per `country_code` and `request_type` at a 10 minute resolution

This is essentially the same as # 1 except you're adding an additional group to the call to `DataFrame.groupby`:

```
In [108]: df.groupby(['country_code', 'request_type']).request_type.resample('10T', how='count')
Out[108]:
country_code  request_type    timestamp
1             get_account     2013-10-10 13:40:00    1
              modify_account  2013-10-10 13:50:00    1
34            get_account     2013-10-10 13:40:00    1
230           get_account     2013-10-10 13:40:00    1
              modify_account  2013-10-10 13:40:00    1
dtype: int64
```

It isn't clear what you're asking for as far as plotting goes, please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, let me clarify: I'd like to see a time based graph (timestamp on the x axis) with the aggregated value on the y axis and one line for each groupby value. So for 1. it would be one line per country_code over time showing the number of hits, for 2. one line per request_type over time showing the 99% percentile at each minute and for 3. one line per country_code/request_type unique pairs showing the hits over time.

Comment: I would suggest reading [the documentation on visualization](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Comment: yes, RTFM, I'm going through it, I'm a bit struggling with the multi-index created by the transformation. I can easily plot an individual groupby key but can't seem to find the 'work as you expect' way of plotting all together on the same graph.